# Obtaining hyperlink text from a web view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am working on an assignment which requires me to open a HTML page in a webview in iPhone. I have a hyperlink which is shown as a string eg. "sometext.fileextensiontype". When this text is clicked it redirects to a link eg. http:www.someweblink.com/uyewihwefkbnamsjdfb".

I am able to intercept the above URL but I want to read the hyperlink string i.e.  sometext.fileextensiontype.

Comment: Where did you intercept the URL? A bit more info or code about it could be useful.

Comment: Never use critical or urgent in your description.

Comment: @ Deepak It is the same code block uploaded by Jhaliya below

Comment: @ Vakio. I have mentioned what it is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is very old and the OP seems to have vanished.

Answer (score 0):

you require to confirm with the [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol and provide implementation to the below `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request     navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

      NSURL *myUrl = [request URL];
      NSString* urlString = [myUrl absoluteString];
      return YES;   
}
```

Comment: Hi, can we add the check if the navigationType is link clicked?

Comment: @ pratikshabhisikar :Sorry ,  Couldn't get you  ?

Comment: He wants to get the url string on its click, so we need to check if the navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked. Else, we would end up always doing that operation, which in my opinion is not necessary.

Comment: Hey @Jhaliya We have already tried that. The method specified by you returns the URL clicked. I am looking out for the text string which is in place of the URL. I am looking to read the text string not the URL string.